# Android - click simulation from service

Tags: android, service

I am trying to simulate a set of clicks outside my app using a service but im not able to perform the clicks.

At the moment i use this example project: [ChatHeads](https://github.com/mollyIV/ChatHeads). So basically i the service initialises the following view:

```
public class HeadLayer extends View {

private Context mContext;
private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;

public HeadLayer(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mContext = context;
    mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);

    addToWindowManager();
}

private void addToWindowManager() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mFrameLayout, params);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Here is the place where you can inject whatever layout you want.
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.head, mFrameLayout);
}

/**
 * Removes the view from window manager.
 */
public void destroy() {
    mWindowManager.removeView(mFrameLayout);
}
```

}

**What do I want to achieve:** After the user switches ON the Service I would like to perform a set of clicks with specific coordinates (X,Y) over the background content.

***Example:*** I open a random app manually, lets say Play Store, then i want my service to perform a set of clicks (with coordinates x/y) over the opened app. For instance perform click on coordinates 123/453 witch on screen matches the link "Games". After this i perform another click with new pair of coordinates, and so on.

How can I perform these click?

Comment: You can't touch outside your app. That would be a security issue.

Comment: I would be touching my transparent Activity/View that let click pass through.